# Sorting special characters specially?

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by, android-sqlite

I have a tablename `contacts` which has columns `[ "id","name","age" ]`.I need to get all the contacts order by name in ascending order.I wrote the following query for it:

```
Select * from contacts order by name collate nocase asc;
```

The results I get from the above above query are following:

```
1. 11 | #ax Nene | 21
1. 21 | 123 Ray | 22
1. 33 | maxy Wel | 25
1. 41 | Max Vele | 23
1. 53 | Nam sing | 25
```

The above ordering is fine but I want names starting with special characters [#,$ or any other non-alphabet] to be at the bottom in the results rather than at top.What should I modify in my query to achieve the desired results.

**NOTE:** I am using sqlite.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation -- You may have to create your own collating function: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_collation.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to prepend some character like `~` (which is sorted after letters) to any such string.
When you do this only in the ORDER BY clause, it affects only the sorting and not the returned values:

```
SELECT *
FROM contacts
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name GLOB '[A-Za-z]*'
              THEN name
              ELSE '~' || name
         END COLLATE NOCASE;
```

(`COLLATE NOCASE` makes the sorting case-insensitive.)

Comment: Your solution worked but now names starting with 'a' comes after name starting with 'Z'. I wanted names starting with 'a' or 'A' to be at same location.

Comment: @user818455 can you use the uppercase or lowercase method for name?

Comment: i think `... WHEN name GLOB '[a-zA-Z]*' ...` will be better. :)

Comment: @CL. np, and thx for ur answer, it helps me figured out the solution for my case :D